# Composing function with identity function yields type mismatch

Tags: java, generics, enums, functional-programming

I have an `enum` and a method that makes custom string-conversion functions for `enum` values:

```
public enum MyEnum {
  DUMMY;
}

public <E extends Enum<E>> Function<E, String> stringify(String suffix) {
  return enumValue -> enumValue.name() + suffix;
}
```

I want to use the method to make a function for my specific enumeration type:

```
public void test() {
  Function<MyEnum, String> f = stringify("");
}
```

That works, but I also need my function to do some follow-on processing to the string.  For the sake of example, let's say the follow-on processing is just the identity function:

```
public void test() {
  Function<MyEnum, String> f = stringify("").andThen(Function.identity());
}
```

Now I get a compile error.  Eclipse (Neon) says:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from `Function<Enum<Enum<E>>,String>` to `Function<Test.MyEnum,String>`

and `javac` says:

```
error: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) V,T#2 exist so that Function<E,V> conforms to Function<MyEnum,String>
        Function<MyEnum, String> f = stringify("").andThen(Function.identity());
                                                      ^
  where V,R,T#1,T#2,E are type-variables:
    V extends Object declared in method <V>andThen(Function<? super R,? extends V>)
    R extends Object declared in interface Function
    T#1 extends Object declared in interface Function
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>identity()
    E extends Enum<E>
```

The return type of `Function.identity()` is the same as its argument type, so I don't see how it changes the overall result to something other than `Function<MyEnum, String>`.  I'm especially confused by the `Enum<Enum<E>>` in the Eclipse error message.

I've noticed that I can avoid the problem by assigning the intermediate result to a variable:

```
public void test() {
  Function<MyEnum, String> f1 = stringify("");
  Function<MyEnum, String> f2 = f1.andThen(Function.identity());
}
```

but I'd rather avoid that if possible.

Why does this type mismatch occur?  What's the best way to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a generics bounding issue.

In this statement:

```
Function<MyEnum, String> f = stringify("").andThen(Function.identity());
```

The compiler does not know the bound for stringify("") and thus cannot infer the bound for `Function.identity()` as well.

To fix this, you need to add a bound to `stringify("")`:

```
Function<MyEnum, String> f = this.<MyEnum>stringify("").andThen(Function.identity());
```

notice the `this` keyword is added as well, since you cannot simply write `<MyEnum>stringify("")`.

If the `stringify("")` method is from some static util class, it will look like the follow instead:

```
Function<MyEnum, String> f = MyUtils.<MyEnum>stringify("").andThen(Function.identity());
```

Comment: Without the `andThen` call, the compiler knows the type bounds for `stringify("")` because it comes from the declared type of `f`.  With the `andThen` call, the result of `stringify("")` is no longer assigned directly to `f`, but I thought the compiler would recognize that the type going into the `andThen` has to be the same as the type coming out of it.  But it sounds like you're saying that the type inference can't work backward like that.

Comment: I might have confused you a bit. The inferred type from the point of view of `.andThen` when not explicitly bounded with a type, is actually `<? extends Enum<?>>`. This is exactly what you defined on the `stringify` method. So in your question, you're effectively assigning a `Function<? extends Enum<?>, String>` to a `Function<MyEnum, String>` which is not allowed.